# How to remove the permission for the user in sharepoint 2010 using java webservices

Tags: java, soap, sharepoint-2010

I try to remove the permission for the particular user in the group in sharepoint 2010, but I am getting following error given below:

> javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: class com.jw.sharepoint.examples.permissions.GetPermissionCollection do not have a property of the name {http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/directory/}objectName
>       at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.BodyBuilder$DocLit.(BodyBuilder.java:202)
>       at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SEIMethodHandler.(SEIMethodHandler.java:81)
>       at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.(SyncMethodHandler.java:84)
>       at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.(SEIStub.java:82)
>       at com.sun.xml.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.createEndpointIFBaseProxy(WSServiceDelegate.java:639)
>       at com.sun.xml.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.getPort(WSServiceDelegate.java:341)
>       at com.sun.xml.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.getPort(WSServiceDelegate.java:323)
>       at com.sun.xml.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.getPort(WSServiceDelegate.java:305)
>       at javax.xml.ws.Service.getPort(Service.java:119)
>       at com.jw.sharepoint.examples.permissions.Permissions.getPermissionsSoap(Permissions.java:49)
>       at com.jw.sharepoint.examples.SharePointBaseExample.getPermissionsSoap(SharePointBaseExample.java:186)
>       at com.jw.sharepoint.examples.SharePointBaseExample.RemovePermission(SharePointBaseExample.java:253)

Code below:

```
private PermissionsSoap getPermissionsSoap() throws Exception {
    URL urlPermission = new URL(getProperties().getProperty("permissions.wsdl"));
    Permissions permissions = new Permissions(urlPermission,new QName("http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/directory/", "Permissions"));
    PermissionsSoap permissionsSoap = permissions.getPermissionsSoap();
    BindingProvider bp = (BindingProvider) permissionsSoap;
    bp.getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.USERNAME_PROPERTY, getProperties().getProperty("username"));
    bp.getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.PASSWORD_PROPERTY, getProperties().getProperty("password"));
    bp.getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS_PROPERTY, getProperties().getProperty("permissions.endpoint"));
    return permissionsSoap;
}
```

Can anyone please give solution to fix this?

Comment: What code are you using?

Comment: using java..i have updated the code above